# Android Studio Progress Bar Orientation not saved

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-orientation, android-savedstate

I currently have a progress bar that tracks the progress on music files however upon different orientation it doesn't seem to want to update and just stuck at the previous location ?

```
 private ProgressBar musicProgress;
    private int updateIncrement;
    private int duration;
    private int progress;
    private int progressUpdate;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_music);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            progressUpdate = savedInstanceState.getInt("PROGRESS");
            duration = savedInstanceState.getInt("Duration");
            updateIncrement = savedInstanceState.getInt("Update");

            musicProgress = findViewById(R.id.p_musicProgress);
            musicProgress.setMax(duration);

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask = new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    musicProgress.setProgress(progressUpdate);
                }
            }, 0, updateIncrement);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("PROGRESS", progressUpdate);
        outState.putInt("Update", updateIncrement);
        outState.putInt("Duration", duration);

    }


    public void onPlayClick (View v)
    {
        Log.d("MP3 Player", "Music Play button pressed");
        if(player.getState() == MP3Player.MP3PlayerState.PAUSED)
        {
            player.play();
        }
        else if(player.getState() == MP3Player.MP3PlayerState.PLAYING)
        {
            player.pause();
        }
        else
        {
            player.load(musicURL, playbackspeed);

            updateIncrement = player.getDuration()/100;
            duration = player.getDuration();
            musicProgress = findViewById(R.id.p_musicProgress);
            musicProgress.setMax(duration);

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask = new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progress = player.getProgress();
                    progressUpdate = progress;
                    musicProgress.setProgress(progressUpdate);
                }
            }, 0, updateIncrement);
        }
    }
```

The issue might be where I set progress = player.getProgress() inside the timer so even after the activity gets destroyed and made again, it'll try to pass the old values inside and continue but then the value gets changed right before the setProgress?

am just really confused at this point

###### EDIT 1:

Also I know the redundent assignement of player.getProgress() I was hoping that using different variables would allow it to change but couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Your `progress` is only updated in the timer started in `onPlayClick()` and this only updates variables within the activity that don't persist when the activity is re-created. As a quick fix, you can check if the state is playing and start a new timer in the `onCreate` method. However, the preferred way to do this would be to decouple your state from your activity entirely and use a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to keep and persist the data throughout the view's lifecycle.

Comment: Isn't that what i've done already in the checking if saved instance is non null ?< also i've just tried to put  another check to see if its playing if it is then it should and its  still the same, the progress bar is still at the last previous position but not continously updating

Comment: you're not calling `progress = player.getProgress();` in the `onCreate` and also not setting `progressUpdate` there (even though that's redundant if it's always going to be set to the value of `progress`) but I will stress that your best option is using a `ViewModel` instead of what you're doing now

Comment: I've done that before but what would happen is it just sets the progress bar back to 0. For whatever reason it would seem like it wont get the progress/ there's not to get unless I get progress after player.load()

Comment: In order to avoid _all_ these issues you need to keep your state in a ViewModel

Comment: I dont really know how to use a viewmodel yet, I tried and even tried using tutorials and i just get seem to get it to work

Comment: I'd suggest trying again and implementing the ViewModel in your app, and then searching or asking a new question here when you run into issues. Feel free to ping me in the comments if you ask a new question and I'll help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much I was on a very tight schedule so I didn't have enough time but I ended up implementing a service that allowed me to update both my progress bar and my music